# Return a value in a function and obtain NULL

Tags: r, function, return

I'm trying to build this function. But I don't know why the output of the function doesn't appear when I call it. 
This is the function that I create:

```
df = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100), nrow=10))
Criterio<-rep('+',7)

modtop<-function(Tpropio,Criterio){
suma<- apply(Tpropio,2,sum)
P<-sweep(Tpropio, 2, suma, `/`) 
maximo<-apply(P,2,max)
minimo<-apply(P,2,min)
desviacion<-apply(P,2,sd)
W<-desviacion/sum(desviacion)
ncriterios<-length(suma)
ideal<-vector(mode="numeric",length=ncriterios)
nadir<-vector(mode="numeric",length=ncriterios)
for(i in 1:ncriterios){
  if(Criterio[i]=='+'){
    ideal[i]=maximo[i]
    nadir[i]=minimo[i]
    }else{
      ideal[i]=minimo[i]
      nadir[i]=maximo[i]
    }
  }
}
dipos<-matrix(data=NA,ncol=ncriterios,nrow=dim(P)[1])
for(i in 1:ncriterios){
  dipos[,i]<-(P[,i]-ideal[i])^2*W[i]
}
dipos<-apply(dipos,1,sum)
dipos<-sqrt(dipos)

dineg<-matrix(data=NA,ncol=ncriterios,nrow=dim(P)[1])
for(i in 1:ncriterios){
  dineg[,i]<-(P[,i]-nadir[i])^2*W[i]
}
dineg<-apply(dineg,1,sum)
dineg<-sqrt(dineg)
T<-dineg+dipos
T<-dineg/T
resulT<-data.frame(T)
row.names(resulT)<-row.names(Tpropio)
return(resulT)
}
```

After defining the function, when I use it I have that a is NULL, but I don't understand why. Thank you for your help and I hope to write an understandable question :D

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer. There was an extra } in the first for. So the result would be this one:

```
df = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100), nrow=10))
Criterio<-rep('+',7)
modtop<-function(Tpropio,Criterio){
suma<- apply(Tpropio,2,sum)
P<-sweep(Tpropio, 2, suma, `/`) 
maximo<-apply(P,2,max)
minimo<-apply(P,2,min)
desviacion<-apply(P,2,sd)
W<-desviacion/sum(desviacion)
ncriterios<-length(suma)
ideal<-vector(mode="numeric",length=ncriterios)
nadir<-vector(mode="numeric",length=ncriterios)
for(i in 1:ncriterios){
  if(Criterio[i]=='+'){
    ideal[i]=maximo[i]
    nadir[i]=minimo[i]
    }else{
      ideal[i]=minimo[i]
      nadir[i]=maximo[i]
    }
  }

dipos<-matrix(data=NA,ncol=ncriterios,nrow=dim(P)[1])
for(i in 1:ncriterios){
  dipos[,i]<-(P[,i]-ideal[i])^2*W[i]
}
dipos<-apply(dipos,1,sum)
dipos<-sqrt(dipos)

dineg<-matrix(data=NA,ncol=ncriterios,nrow=dim(P)[1])
for(i in 1:ncriterios){
  dineg[,i]<-(P[,i]-nadir[i])^2*W[i]
}
dineg<-apply(dineg,1,sum)
dineg<-sqrt(dineg)
T<-dineg+dipos
T<-dineg/T
resulT<-data.frame(T)
row.names(resulT)<-row.names(Tpropio)
return(resulT)
}
```